# Place for team leader or project leader in Scrum

Tags: scrum, leadership, project-leader

What is a role of team/project leader in scrum? In or organization team/project leader is doing:

- Communicate with PO which is customer
- Help team to find solutions
- Help PO to define direction
- Help to deliver complete solution

How team/leader can find out in scrum or even is make send to have this position in team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scrum answer would be that there isn't a team leader. The Scrum Guide states that:

> Scrum recognizes no titles for Development Team members, regardless of the work being performed by the person

The things that you mention - communication with the Product Owner, discovery of solutions, definition of direction, delivery of a complete solution - all fall to a self-organizing, cross-functional Development Team that does not recognize titles or sub-teams. By making these functions owned by the whole Development Team, it forces the entire team to step up and take responsibility for the success, or the failure, of the effort.

In practice, though, there may be people who are skilled at particular work, including architectural design (which I would say includes defining a technical direction and helping the team discover solutions). Initially, a person with this skill set may take on the bulk of this work. But to promote cross-functionality, they should be educating and helping other members of the Development Team skill up. Any specialist should be doing that - teaching the other members their skills so they do not become a bottleneck on the team.

Answer (score 0):

Note: For the sake of clarity, the team leader in question within a Scrum Team shall be known as Bob.

Since a team lead or project leader is a position of authority, the role cannot be directly mapped to a position within a Scrum Team. Authoritarian roles do not exist within Scrum.

However, the skills required for leading teams can be mapped to tasks within a Scrum Team, provided Bob is willing to forego wearing a badge of honour and take on a role of service (I have been in a team where this has not happened and it just led to unnecessary conflict).

*Communicate with the Product Owner (PO), which is customer*: If this is a skill that Bob is good at, then it will be useful for the greater effort.

*Help the Team to find solutions*: All members of the Team are responsible for finding solutions, but Bob's experience might be able to help guide efforts in this regard.

*Help the PO to define direction*: Bob's experience may be useful in guiding this process and communicating the direction between the Team and the PO.

*Help to deliver a complete solution*: Once again, the whole Team is responsible for delivering a complete solution. Bob's experience can play a role here. There is also some 'paperwork' that needs to be done, such as cleaning up tickets and task clarification, in which Bob's experience may help.

Ultimately, it boils down to Bob's mindset. If he is willing to be a part of the team effort, there will be no shortage of tasks.